# Image (Error) Property 'NDVI' of feature '0_0' is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, classification

when I was working on classification for crop mapping to find maize fields, I faced the error.
I made samples using geometry and named it trainingdata which indicate maize fields.
Besides I tried shape file of fields as trainingdata but the same error appeared.
would you mind help me?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4225b4f0c80daa5e90c65eb55e0c71fb

```
// Load the satellite imagery
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(studyArea)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .select(['B2','B3','B4', 'B8', 'B11']);

// Compute vegetation indices
var calculateIndices = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  var evi = image.expression('2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
    'NIR': image.select('B8'),
    'RED': image.select('B4'),
    'BLUE': image.select('B2')
  }).rename('EVI');
  var gndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B3']).rename('GNDVI');
  var savi = image.expression('(1.5 * (NIR - RED)) / (NIR + RED + 0.5)', {
    'NIR': image.select('B8'),
    'RED': image.select('B4')
  }).rename('SAVI');
  
  // Compute LAI (Leaf Area Index) using EVI
  var lai = image.expression('2.5 * EVI', {'EVI': evi}).rename('LAI');
  
  return image.addBands([ndvi, evi, gndvi, savi, lai]);
};

// Apply the vegetation index calculation to the image collection
var processedCollection = imageCollection.map(calculateIndices);

// Merge the training data with the processed image collection
var trainingImage = processedCollection.select(['NDVI', 'EVI', 'GNDVI', 'SAVI', 'LAI'])
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
  .sampleRegions({
    collection: trainingData,
    properties: ['NDVI', 'EVI', 'GNDVI', 'SAVI', 'LAI', 'Area'],
    scale: 10
  });


// Define the input bands for Random Forest classifier
var inputBands = ['NDVI', 'EVI', 'GNDVI', 'SAVI', 'LAI'];

// Train the Random Forest classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
  features: trainingImage,
  classProperty: 'Area',
  inputProperties: inputBands
});

// Classify the processed image collection
var classifiedCollection = processedCollection.select(inputBands)
  .map(function(image) {
    var classifiedImage = image.classify(classifier);
    return classifiedImage.rename('classification').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
  });

// Threshold the classified collection to obtain corn fields
var cornFields = classifiedCollection.map(function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select('classification').gt(0));
});

// Calculate the area of corn fields
var fieldArea = cornFields.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('classification').multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
});

// Calculate the total corn field area
var cornFieldArea = fieldArea.sum().divide(10000); // Divide by 10000 to get area in hectares

// Print the estimated corn field area
print('Corn Field Area (in hectares):', cornFieldArea);
```